# Submission to Apple for app doesn't run the same locally vs at Apple with Parse.com backend

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm hoping another developer has come across this somewhere. I have an app I have been trying to get approved by Apple. The interesting thing is the app behaves differently while running locally on my iPhone and in the iOS Simulator. Specifically when a new user signs up I am checking a flag as to if the Users have agreed to the apps Terms and Conditions. In Parse the column is set to `undefined` until they agree then it goes to `true`. This works fine in all my testing. But at Apple it is not and is not triggering the Agree to Terms condition. Here is the code for that check:

```
if((PFUser.currentUser()!["termsAgreed"]) != nil) {
            termsAgreed = PFUser.currentUser()!["termsAgreed"] as! Bool
            if !termsAgreed {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("agreeTerms", sender: nil)
            }

        }
        else {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("agreeTerms", sender: nil)
```

I made a new change to see if it helps, in that when a user signs up I set `PFUser.currentUser()!["termsAgreed"]` to `false` before this check

I'm hoping that enforces the terms agreement condition to fail on Apples end but would like some feedback from anyone experiencing something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your actual question might be, using force unwrapping is not considered quite safe. Your code would be much more stable like this:

```
if let termsAgreed = PFUser.currentUser()?["termsAgreed"] as? Bool where
    !termsAgreed {
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("agreeTerms", sender: nil)
}
else {
   // proceed
}
```

PS: I hope that is syntactically correct - I have no IDE at hand atm.